# Keyboard & Mouse suddenly stopped working on login screen & desktop but not boot, yet USB peripheral devices still work

Tags: debian, keyboard, mouse

bit of an issue here with some interesting details.

Running Debian 9 on an older laptop with some wear and tear, but bear with me! The computer crashed suddenly and I had to reboot, and when I did, the laptop trackpad / keyboard aren't working on the login screen or desktop after logging in.

What's strange though is that the keyboard and mouse DO work while booting up (I can use the keyboard to toggle through the bios and boot menus) and I can attach a peripheral keyboard + mouse via USB to the device and get it working then. The only times they (the laptop's) don't work is when I'm at the login screen and on my desktop windows after logging in.

I was wondering how I could fix it so that my laptop's own keyboard / trackpad would work again after I've logged in? This doesn't seem like a hardware issue since the keyboard works fine in the boot menus.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

and rebooted, but no luck.

Thanks and happy to provide more info or logs if anyone wants, just not sure where to begin myself here.

Comment: Try with a live distro on an USB stick ?

Comment: That will probably work, along with reinstalling the OS like it did for this person https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38747/keyboard-and-mouse-do-not-function-in-debian?rq=1 but I'm hoping there's a quicker solution out there. I unfortunately have to keep working on this device at least until the weekend so I'll need access to all my files in the meantime