# No keyboard or mouse input at all in debian installer

Tags: debian-installer

Plugged into motherboard USB doesnt work, Plugged into USB hub doesnt work, hell even my PS/2 keyboard doesnt work (Yes, i am aware someone had this same issue but i am not able to fix it in the way he did [Keyboard and mouse do not function in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38747/keyboard-and-mouse-do-not-function-in-debian) ) Keep in mind im a linux noob so please try to keep it simple

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Alright so apparently it decided to work now and everything is fine?

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the BIOS settings. Does the keyboard work there (PS/2 or USB)? If not, there might be a hardware fault of some kind.

If the BIOS has PS/2 emulation for USB mouse and keyboard enabled, try switching them off: sometimes poorly implemented PS/2 emulation for legacy OSs can cause problems for OSs that have real USB drivers.

Comment: Keyboard works fine in BIOS